# function returning empty set

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword)
{
    ItemSet temp;

    for(it=bookList.begin();it!=bookList.end();it++){
        if(it->getPtr()->findKeyWord(it->getPtr()->keywordsList, keyword))
            temp.insert(*it);
    }

    ItemSet* temp2 = &temp;
    return temp2;
}
```

ItemSet is a set which contains instances of ItemPtr, which contains pointers to instances of derived classes.  'it' is an iterator defined in Library, findKeyWord is a function that compares the keywordsList to the keyword to determine if that keyword is in that list.  if it returns true, then I dereference the iterator, and add the instance it is currently iterating to temp.  My issue is, when it is done with the loop, I return the temp2, but it returns empty, and causes an error when my print function goes to print it.  Why is it returning empty?  Thanks.

Comment: temp gets destroyed where the scope ends. The returned pointer is called dangling after that...

Answer (score 6):

You're returning a pointer to the local object which gets destroyed on returning from the function. That is surely undefined behavior.

Also, I don't see why you need to return pointer. You could return the object itself:

```
ItemSet Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword)
{
   ItemSet temp;
   //your code
   return temp;
}
```

If you need to return pointer, then I would suggest you to return smart pointer, rather than raw pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<ItemSet> Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword)
{
   std::unique_ptr<ItemSet> temp(new ItemSet());
   //your code, use this syntax =>  temp->insert(*it);
   return std::move(temp);
}
```

Comment: I need to return the pointer, because main is defined in a way that is not allowed to be changed per the instructor.  We were given a 'skeleton' to insert our code into, this function was empty and I was to fill it in, so I don't think I can change anything but write the code inside.  So I do need to return the pointer, but not sure if I can use a raw pointer.  Is there any other way?

Comment: @IanLindquist: If you're not allowed to use smart pointer either, then you have to stick with `ItemSet *temp = new ItemSet()`, then insert data to it as `temp->insert(*it)`, then `return temp;`. But **remember**, once you're done with the returned pointer, you've to manually do `delete returnedPtr;` to deallocate the memory.

Comment: that simple fix did the trick.  Thanks, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: If you are going to use move semantics then just make ItemSet movable and move that. If it's just a typedef of an STL collection then it should already be movable.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the address of a local variable, this will not work.

Either supply an item as an argument to the function which you modify or allocate an item in your function and return its address.

Answer (score 1):

After you comment with instructor, and main code...

```
ItemSet* Library::itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword)
{
    ItemSet* p_temp = new ItemSet;

    for(it=bookList.begin();it!=bookList.end();it++){
        if(it->getPtr()->findKeyWord(it->getPtr()->keywordsList, keyword))
            p_temp->insert(*it);
    }

    return p_temp;
}
```

EDIT: you should show to your instructor @Nawaz example :)

Answer (score 0):

You must not return addresses of objects allocated on stack. After the function returns the objects on the stack are destroyed and the pointer is pointing to some garbage.